# Rails/SQL: Group and sum query based on a relational value shared in different table columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

I have three tables: `Fee`, `Project` and `Company`:

```
------------------   ------------------    ------------------
|      Fee       |   |     Project    |    |     Company    |
------------------   ------------------    ------------------
| fee:float      |   | id:int         |    | id:int         |  
| project_id:int |   | currency:string|    | currency:string|
| ...            |   | company_id:int |    | ...            |
------------------   | ...            |    ------------------
                     ------------------
```

Each `Company` has many `Projects` and a `Project` typically has many `Fees`. I am trying to group (and sum) `Fees` by their currency type which, for legacy reasons is now set either on `Projects` or on `Companies` (a mess I know, but one I've inherited).

The following `ActiveRecord` queries nearly do what I require, but not quite:

```
Fee.all.joins(project: :company)
       .group('projects.currency, companies.currency').sum(:fee)
...
=> {"USD"=>100893.0, "AUD"=>320.0, "GBP"=>10279.99, nil=>4242.42}
.
.
.
Fee.all.joins(project: :company)
       .group('companies.currency, projects.currency').sum(:fee)
...
=> {nil=>10279.99, "KRW"=>4242.42}
```

I can't figure out how to have both currency columns from (`Project` and `Company`) summed correctly in a single query which would return a result like so:

```
 => {"USD"=>100893.0, "AUD"=>320.0, "GBP"=>10279.99, "KRW"=>4242.42}
```

I could solve this by joining and grouping by one table and column at a time then totalling the results programatically, but that feels clumsy.

EDIT: The full snippet for the first query above (note `Fee` is implemented as `FeeMilestone`):

```
[2] pry(main)> FeeMilestone.joins(project: :company).group('projects.currency, companies.currency').sum(:fee)

(11.0ms)  SELECT SUM("fee_milestones"."fee") AS sum_fee, projects.currency, companies.currency AS projects_currency_companies_currency FROM "fee_milestones" INNER JOIN "projects" ON "projects"."id" = "fee_milestones"."project_id" INNER JOIN "companies" ON "companies"."id" = "projects"."company_id" GROUP BY projects.currency, companies.currency

=> {"USD"=>100893.0, "AUD"=>320.0, "GBP"=>10279.99, nil=>4242.42}
```

I'm hoping to get the `Projects.currency` to return instead of `nil` above (it would be `"KRW"` in my dev environment).

Comment: try passing `COALESCE(projects.currency, companies.currency)` to the `group` option

Comment: Bang on---that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @jvnill, I've been stuck for ages. Could you copy/paste as an answer so I could accept it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `COALESCE` function which will go through the parameters pass to it and get the first one that isn't `NULL`.  Since projects belong to companies, I'm assuming that the currency in the project take precedence over the one in the company so pass `projects.currency` first.

```
COALESCE(projects.currency, companies.currency)
```